# Conditional interface in Kotlin

Tags: swift, interface, kotlin, swift-protocols

In Swift, we can define a protocol that can be conformed by a `class` or `struct` based on condition:

```
protocol AlertPresentable {
   func presentAlert(message: String)
}

extension AlertPresentable where Self : UIViewController {

 func presentAlert(message: String) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: “Alert”, message: message,  preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: “OK”, style: .default, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

}
```

The `AlertPresentable` protocol is restricted and can only be conformed by an `UIViewController`. Is there a way to achieve the same result in Kotlin?

Comment: *"The AlertPresentable protocol is restricted and can only be conformed by an UIViewController."*. Thats not technically true. I can still conform to AlertPresentable with any other struct/class that contains a function `func presentAlert(message: String)`. The above extension is just the default implementation for a UIViewController

Comment: Looks like a regular Kotlin extension function to me: `fun UIViewController.presentAlert(message: String) { ... }`

Comment: @yole by doing so, the `presentAlert(message: String)` is available to all `UIViewController`. What if I want this method to be available only to those implementing `AlertPresentable` ?

Comment: @Benjamin I think, in that case you would define extension function for `AlertPresentable`

Comment: @StefanGolubović I agree but in that case, you don't have access to methods defined on `UIViewController `

Comment: JFYI, it's a bit rude, deleting your question after it's been answered.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev sorry, I realized my question was dumb... I didn't pay attention enough before asking! thank you anyway

Comment: @Benjamin: just don't do this in the future. Dumb or not, someone spent their time to help you. It's the least you could do to reward them with some internet points. Might be useful to others too. But yes, by all means, spend as much effort as you can before posting :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to accomplish, you can use an extension function with multiple types as upper bounds of the receiver type:

```
fun <T> T.presentAlert(message: String) 
    where T : UIViewController, T : AlertPresentable {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to override this kind of extension ? I tried but I didn't found.

Comment: You cannot override any kind of extension. Extensions are always resolved statically.

Answer (score 0):

Although quite late but I just want to clarify that the assumption in the question is wrong.
The extension in the question means that the default implementation is only available for object of type "UIViewController".
However, The protocol itself can be implemented by any other type of objects. It will only need to have its own implementation of the "presentAlert" function.